# Cant reach variable using include blade templates

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

So I have this structure in my app.blade.php

If statement check if user have subscription and if no shows sub page else show dashboard
[image]

I send all required variables to dashboard view like this

[image]

But when I'm trying to get variable in before-payment view I cant reach it.

[image]

I test it without If statement in Dashboard I can use all variables. So how can I use variables in this situation?

Comment: on blade `$plan->id ?? null` or `$plan->id ?: null`

Comment: I need this variable and data, but it only works when it show dashboard page, but I need to use data if statement on first screenshot wirks

Comment: @ДимаСвободин If you want those values to be present or be injected in multiple views, have a look at view composers or view::share methods in Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its better if u passing to global view via AppServiceProvider ( boot function ).

Just add :

```
$plan = Plan::first();
view()->share('plan', $plan);
```